# How to provide database name in Data Migration Assistant tool

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, data-migration

I am using Data Migration Assistant to move the data to Azure Sql

I have servername, database name, username, and password.

I want to provide database name with server name while the request is send because my database user does not have the master database permission.

Is there any way so that i can provide the database name with the Server, as my user has database level permission.

Comment: Try to use SQL Server Data Tools instead as explained here. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2012/04/19/migrating-a-database-to-sql-azure-using-ssdt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DMA needs not only database level permissions. It needs server level permissions since it needs to examine and migrate SQL logins at the server level and at the database level.

DMA not only moves your database schema and data, but also uncontained objects from your source server to your target server.

There is no way to use DMA with only database level permissions.

Try to use SQL Server Data Tools instead as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2012/04/19/migrating-a-database-to-sql-azure-using-ssdt/).

Hope this helps.